# Verify if $W$ is a linearly independent subset of $\mathbb{F}^x$

Tags: linear-algebra

The full wording of the question is:

Let $X$ be an infinite set. For each $a \in F$, consider the function $f_a : X \to F$, given by $f_a(x) := 1$, if $x = a$, and $f_a(x) := 0$, if $x \neq a$. Let $W$ be the set formed by these functions. Show that $W$ is a linear independent subset of $\mathbb{F}^x$

**My attempt:**

Before testing whether $W$ is linearly independent, I started by checking whether $W$ is a subset of $\mathbb{F}^x$. However, I had a question: if all functions are defined and can take on a value $0$ or $1$, how could I say that $0(x) \in W$, expressed by:

$$0(x) = 0, \quad \forall x \in X$$

If the null vector doesn't belong to $W$, I can't say that $W$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{F}^x$.

Because of this, $W$ is not a subspace of $\mathbb{F}^x$, since $0 \notin W$. Am I right?

Comment: You are right $W$ is not a subspace, but you didn't answer the question - look carefully at what it asks :)

Comment: But how could I say that $W$ is a linearly independent subspace of $\mathbb{F}^n$ if $W$ is not a subspace?

Comment: It's not a "subspace". The question asks if it is a linearly independent sub**set**. No subspace is *ever* a linearly independent set, because they always contain the zero vector.

Comment: my bad. thank you very much

Comment: Is it true that $\lambda_1 f_{a_1}+\cdots + \lambda_nf_{a_n} = 0$ implies that $\lambda_1=\cdots=\lambda_n=0$ whenever $n\geq 1$ and $a_1,\ldots, a_n\in X$ are fixed? This is what you have to check.